# Firebase Add New Key/Value to Pre-existing database without crashing xcode

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
`    let query = ref?.child("Reviews").queryOrdered(byChild: "UserID").queryEqual(toValue: myUser.userId)
        query?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                let uid = dict["UserID"] as! String
                let review = dict["Body"] as! String
                let rating = dict["Rating"] as! String
                let titleID = dict["TitleID"] as! String
                let reviewID = dict["ReviewID"] as! String

                let ratingID = dict["RatingID"] as! String
                `
```

THE ERROR OCCURS AT THE ratingID call to the database. It unwraps nil.

I am trying to adapt a pre existing Firebase database with a new key/value.
I then try to display entries in my tableview and I get a crash with unwrap returning nil. I know why this is happening and it's because the previous data does not have the new key/value I want to include in the node going forward. I have tried many different things such as if let and guard let without much fortune. How do I add new key/Values and still have the tableview read entries that don't have the new value?

I include an image of the current node and I want to add a 'RatingsID' to the node. When I do, I get the unwrap nil error.

Database node prior to new key/value

[image]

Comment: I can't find a reference to this anywhere on the net!

Comment: Please include your code as that's where the issue is and also indicate on what line the error is occurring. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay i just added code. I already know what the problem is, my issue is how to cater for old entries that do not have a Rating ID key value without re doing all my entries with the new format. ie I want to be able to adapt my key value pairs in future say adding likes and follows to a node if I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is super close, just need to protect the code in case the ratingID key doesn't exist.

So change

```
let ratingID = dict["RatingID"] as! String
```

to

```
let ratingID = dict["RatingID"] as! String ?? ""
```

So if the RatingID node does not exist, you'll set ratingID to an empty string (or whatever string you want)

You could also code it to only operate on the value of that key if the node exists (not nil)

```
if let someVal = dict["xxx"] {
    //do something with someVal
} else {
    print("xxx node wasn't found")
}
```

Here's a complete example: We are reading some messages from the messages node and some of them have a test_key node and some dont. For those that don't, *default string* is assigned to test

```
let postsRef = self.ref.child("messages")
postsRef.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
    let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let msg = dict["msg"] as! String
    let test = dict["test_key"] ?? "default string"
    print(msg, test)
}
```

Comment: hmm im still getting unwrapped to nil error when I try that ?? "" method

Comment: The issue might be because the RatingID value pair doesn't exist on that particular entry?

Comment: I fixed it by changing the ! to ? after as

Comment: That's the whole idea. If dict["RatingID"] doesn't exist, the the var ratingID will be set to an empty string "", whereas if it does exist, whatever the value is will be assigned to the var.